# How can I show show question answers in django class view?

Tags: python, django

In my models.py file I hav 2 classes Question and Answer.And in views.py file I am using ready class forms from django.views.generic. So how can I show question answers in detailview HTML?

models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    author  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title   = models.CharField('Title', max_length=70)
    content = models.TextField('Body', null=True, blank=True)
    date    = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('current', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questions'
        verbose_name        = 'Question'

class Answer(models.Model):
    author   = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content  = models.TextField('Body', null=True, blank=True)
    date     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'
        verbose_name        = 'Answer'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .models import Question, Answer
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)

def index(request):
    context = {
        'questions': Question.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'f/index.html', context)

class QuestionListView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'f/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'questions'
    ordering = ['-date']

class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model   = Question
    answers = Answer

class QuestionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model  = Question
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

question_detail.html
in this file is detail for every question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ object.title }} - :) </title>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="circle-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
    <p class="question-title">{{ object.title }}</p>
    <p class="question-body">{{ object.content }}</p>
    <p class="post-date">{{ object.date|date:"F d, Y" }}</p>
    
    {% if object.author == user %}
        <div>
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'question-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'question-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
        <script>
            console.log('You are the author of this question :3');
        </script>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

I have created Answer to Question in admin page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [reverse query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) to get `Answer` objects from `Question` instance. Like this:

```
# template: question_detail.html

{% for answer in object.answer_set.all %}
     {{ answer.content }}
     {{ answer.author }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes thanks, but how is gonna look QuestionDetailView in views.py?

Comment: You just need to remove `answers = Answer` from that view. That part of code has no functionality there.